# Changing the timezone value in /postgresql.conf when select perticular timezone from the UI

Tags: postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

I have multiple timezone support in my project. I have requirement to change the timezone of postgressql.conf when changing the timezone. I am using cakephp - php scripting language. I can use python script to update timezone value in postgresql.conf file as it might be issue to change postgresql.conf file from php as Apache won't be all privileges. Currently when user change timezone I am restarting my appliance to set the timezone for appliance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any luck? You might want to explain in a bit more detail if the answer I posted doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead just `SET TimeZone = 'whatever'` in each SQL session at the start of the connection or use `ALTER DATABASE ... SET TIME ZONE` or `ALTER USER ... SET TIME ZONE`.

That way you don't have to alter `postgresql.conf` and reload the server each time.